# How do I make the label change direction when it hits the wall?

Tags: c#

I have a tiny problem, I want to create a label that moves slowly to the wall and when hit the walls it should return back to the other wall. I made the label go left but after a while it will go through the form and disappear, is it possible to make it turn right (other direction) when it hits the form? So it goes from wall to wall?

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;

    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Left = label1.Left + 10;
    }
```

Comment: you can use Form Width as Wall. when your label position== form width, then decrement the position by 10

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the width you have available and the width of the label text, then you can create a condition that says that when the `currentPosition + labelWidth >= availableWidth` then move the other way. And of course you will have another similar condition for the left side of the screen.

My suggestion:

```
private int velocity = 10;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

 if (currentWidth + labelWidth >= availableWidth)
    {
        //set velocity to move left
        velocity = -10;
    }
 else if (currentWidth - labelWidth <= 0)
    {
        //set velocity to move right
        velocity = 10;
    }
 label1.Left = label1.Left + velocity;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sounds like homework to me... just in case it isn't:

private int direction = 1;
private int speed = 10;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    direction = 1;
    timer1.Enabled = true;

}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if( label1.Left + label1.Width > this.Width && direction == 1 ){
        direction = -1;
    }
    if( label1.Left <= 0 && direction == -1 ){
        direction = 1;
    }
    label1.Left = label1.Left + (direction * speed);
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! I was stuck for so long because i really needed that code! (i'm working on something big!)

Comment: You should use `ClientSize.Width` because `Width` contains the borders. Also: why not just change the sign of `speed`? `if (label1.Left < 0 || label1.Left + label1.Width > ClientSize.Width) speed = -speed; label1.Left += speed;`

Comment: upvote for `ClientSize.Width` and I did it so verbosely for explanatory reasons and also, if the label width changes (grows while going left from the right border), it might get stuck...